# Access scope function on ng-click on navbar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my markup

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app">
    <header ng-include="'templates/nav.html'"></header>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Here, `nav.html` isn't a `view` and doesn't have the reference to any controller. In this case, if I have to execute some function on `ng-click` of a button in `nav.html`, where do I write that method? Should it be in `rootScope`? Not sure, I might be wrong.

Please guide in the right direction.

Comment: I think you should create a directive that encapsulate the navbar and then the directive it self can contain the function or delegate to a function that could be set on the parent template

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the controller in your nav.html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
...
</div>
```

Declare the controller as follows:

```
var module = angular.module('app');
module.controller('myController', myController);
function myController($scope) {
  //Write function here
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment suggesting the reason for downvote. So that I don't make that mistake again, provided it's a mistake.

Comment: Well I think you failed to understand the real problem here. What you've explained in your answer is the most basic thing about AngularJS that any beginner would know. The real question was how to link an `ng-include`d element with a controller.

Comment: Hmm. the option that I can think of at the top of my head is using ng-controller in the template but that is clearly not the option as is suggested in the question itself. So, please enlighten me @Салман.

Comment: Good idea! But I don't see how the question says it isn't an option? I'll try it anyway. Thanks. May be you can edit and post that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app">
    <my-header> </my-header>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>

//JS
//Previous code
.directive('myHeader', function(){
  return {
   templateUrl : 'templates/nav.html',
   controller : [function(){
      //Here you are
   }]

  };
});
```